# Cython primes example - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, cython

I am learning Cython in Linux and am working though the example on the Cython Tutorial pages:

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#primes

I am studying the primes example.  Which has the code:

```
def primes(int nb_primes):
    cdef int n, i, len_p
    cdef int p[1000]
    if nb_primes > 1000:
        nb_primes = 1000

    len_p = 0  # The current number of elements in p.
    n = 2
    while len_p < nb_primes:
        # Is n prime?
        for i in p[:len_p]:
            if n % i == 0:
                break

        # If no break occurred in the loop, we have a prime.
        else:
            p[len_p] = n
            len_p += 1
        n += 1

    # Let's return the result in a python list:
    result_as_list  = [prime for prime in p[:len_p]]
    return result_as_list
```

I have saved the code as primes.pyx and run the setup.py.

which looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("primes.pyx")
)
```

However when I import primes using

```
>>> import primes
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/merlin/scoleman/test_cython/primes.py", line 1
    def primes(int nb_primes):
```

I have `primes.c` and `primes.pyx` files. Why do I get this error?

Comment: The syntax of your first 3 lines is incorrect.

Comment: would you be good enough to let me know what is wrong with them.....

Comment: Instead of `int x`, try `int(x)` to turn it into an integer

Comment: Have you run the steps as outlined earlier in the tutorial, e.g., imports and `setup(ext_modules=cythonize("primes.pyx")...`? Also, your error message shows that the file is `primes.py`, not `primes.pyx` as it ought to be

Comment: G.Anderson - Yes I ran the setup (I have added the code to the question). Sorry but am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a step to build it into `pyd`.

Create a `setup.py` :

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("primes.pyx"),
)
```

and run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in command line to build it.

**These are at the top half of your document.**